# my post request status to Reqres api is always 400 and i get the registration fail response

Tags: ajax, vue.js

my post request status to Reqres api is always 400 and i get the registration fail response though the json i send is similar to the valid one of the api

**this is my HTML**

```
        <input v-model="mail" type="email" />
        <input v-model="pass" type="password" />
        <button @click="reg">register</button>
    </div>
```

**this is the JS ()**

```
var vm = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        mail: "",
        pass: ""
    },
    methods: {
        reg: function () {

            var obj = {
                email: this.mail,
                password: this.pass
            }


            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

            xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    console.log(xhr.responseText);
            }

            xhr.open('POST', 'https://reqres.in/api/register');
            xhr.send(JSON.stringify(obj));
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> A generic API that conforms to REST principles and accepts a content type of
> `application/json`

Set `Content-Type` header to `application/json` before running `.send()`

```js
xhr.open('POST', 'https://reqres.in/api/register');
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
xhr.send(JSON.stringify(obj));
```